# Игра «больше-меньше» где-то упускает сравнение

Tags: java

Программа на паттерне MVC недополучает в do-while значение inputNumber, не вижу, что нужно исправить. Уже и передавать прямо в цикл пытался (выдает постоянно введенное число), и создавал циклично сканнер, что тоже не верно. Далее код:

MAIN

```
package com.MoreLessMVC;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = new Model();
        View view = new View();
        Controller controller = new Controller(model, view);
        controller.userProcess();
    }

}
```

CONTROLLER

```
package com.MoreLessMVC;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Controller {

    public static final double RANDOM_NUMBER = Math.random()*100;
    public static final int CORRECT_NUMBER = (int) RANDOM_NUMBER;

    private Model model;
    private View view;

    public Controller(Model model, View view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void userProcess() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputNumber = 0;

        model.setInputNumber(inputNumber(scan));

        view.printMessage(String.valueOf(model.getInputNumber()));
    }

    public int inputNumber(Scanner scan) {
        do {
            inputNumber = scan.nextInt();
            if(inputNumber < 0 || inputNumber > 100){
                view.printMessage(View.WRONG_INPUT);
            } else if(CORRECT_NUMBER > inputNumber){
                view.printMessage(View.WRONG_LESS);
            } else if(CORRECT_NUMBER < inputNumber){
                view.printMessage(View.WRONG_MORE);
            } else {
                System.out.println("You guessed it!");
            }
        } while (inputNumber != CORRECT_NUMBER);
        return inputNumber;
    }

}
```

VIEW

```
package com.MoreLessMVC;

public class View {
    public static final String WRONG_INPUT = "Error! You need to input the number that should be in the range from 0 to 100!";
    public static final String WRONG_LESS = "Less than you need.";
    public static final String WRONG_MORE = "More than you need.";


    public void printMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

}
```

MODEL

```
package com.MoreLessMVC;

public class Model {
    private int inputNumber;

    public int getInputNumber() {
        return inputNumber;
    }

    public void setInputNumber(int inputNumber) {
        this.inputNumber = inputNumber;
    }

}
```

Comment: Почему inputNumber  объявлен в одном методе, а используется в совсем другом? Как так получилось что имя этой *бедной* переменной совпадает с именем метода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Введите вне тела цикла переменную `inputNumber` типа `int`.

```java
public int inputNumber(Scanner scan) {
    int inputNumber;//ВОТ
    do {
        inputNumber = scan.nextInt();
        if(inputNumber < 0 || inputNumber > 100){
            view.printMessage(View.WRONG_INPUT);
        } else if(CORRECT_NUMBER > inputNumber){
            view.printMessage(View.WRONG_LESS);
        } else if(CORRECT_NUMBER < inputNumber){
            view.printMessage(View.WRONG_MORE);
        } else {
            System.out.println("You guessed it!");
        }
    } while (inputNumber != CORRECT_NUMBER);
    return inputNumber;
}
```